# Is there a hook when a relation is created, updated or deleted?

Tags: hooks, entities

I know how to use hooks like `hook_node_presave`. Is there also a hook to catch the deletion of a relation or the update of a relation? In the [API](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21relation%21relation.module/7) I cannot find anything.
Maybe there is a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relations are themselves entities, so you can use the entity hooks:

- [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7)
- [`hook_entity_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7)
- [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7)

and so on, checking the `$type` parameter to react only for the appropriate entity type(s).

There's a full list of available entity hooks in the [system.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/7) file.